# Validation Error: Bad value for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point

Tags: php, html-table

I am pulling database information and displaying it in a table, the content of the title column is linked to a dynamic page. It all works perfectly but when validating my output page with the W3C Validator I get the following error and have no idea how to fix it!

> Bad value newpage.php?url= DATABASE INFORMATION for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.

It then highlights the end tag for the a href ">".

```
<?php 
    echo"<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </tr>
    </table>";


        if (mysqli_num_rows($SQLresult) == 0 ) 
        { 
            echo 'No results found, please try again.';
        } 
        else 
        {   
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SQLresult)) 
            {
                echo "
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href='newpage.php?url=".$row['title']."'>".$row['title']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['A']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['B']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['C']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['D']."</td>
                </tr>
                </table>";
            }          
        }
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "when validating my output page..." It would help to see that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all characters are legal in URLs.  Those that are not legal can be recoded using the percent sign and two hex digits.  PHP's `urlencode()` function does that. Use `urlencode()` on the part that is to be the link.

```
$url = urlencode($row['title']);
...
 <td><a href='newpage.php?url=".$url."'>".$row['title']."</td>
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
<td><a href='newpage.php?url=".urlencode($row['title'])."'>".$row['title']."</td>
```

You can find more information about legal characters in URL/URI in RFC2396: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2